# Scala, add sum of last two items of list to that same list

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and I'm trying run an operation on elements of the list and I want to add the result to the end of the same list.

right now I have

```
func(pos - 1 , list) :: func(pos - 1 , list).takeRight(2).sum
```

which does the job but is very ugly and calls "func" twice.  I'd rather have something like:

```
func(pos - 1 , list).<somefunction>.takeright(2).sum
```

but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Show an example of the inputs and expected output.

Comment: I would suggest against using a `List` if you need to append. `List`s are fast for *prepending*, but very slow for *appending*. Consider using a `Vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why your working code should be ugly, but you can get rid of the redundant method-call by storing the result in a local variable. It looks like you want to append the sum of the two last items to the list, so you would want to use the `:+` operator instead of `::`, though keep in mind that appending takes linear time whereas prepending to a list is constant, so you should prefer the latter.

So what you could do is

```
val intermediate: List[Int] = func(pos - 1, list)
intermediate :+ intermediate.takeRight(2).sum
```

However, just to show you what can be done in Scala, here an example that comes closer to your desired output:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println(func(4, Nil).append(_.takeRight(2).sum)) // List(1, 2, 3, 5)
}

def func(i: Int, l: List[Int]): List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

implicit class PimpMyList(list: List[Int]) {
  def append(f: List[Int] => Int): List[Int] = {
    list :+ f(list)
  }
}
```

By defining an implicit class you can simulate a richer interface and add a new method `append` to the interface of `List`. Note that now, `list.append(x)` is just the implicit syntax for `new PimpMyList(list).append(x)`. `append` takes a function that translates a `List[Int]` to an `Int`, so we can call this with the function `x => x.takeRight(2).sum` as desired.

Note that we could also make our implicit class generic:

```
implicit class PimpMyList[T](list: List[T]) {
  def append(f: List[T] => T): List[T] = {
    list :+ f(list)
  }
}

println(List("foo", "bar", "baz").append(_.takeRight(2).reduce(_ + _))) // List(foo, bar, baz, barbaz)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` to apply some transformation to the result of some expression:

```
List(1,2,3) match {
  case x => x :+ x.takeRight(2).sum
}

//>> List(1, 2, 3, 5)
```